# Package "boost_atomic" NOT FOUND when running CMake

Tags: linux, boost, cmake, rstudio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install RStudio Desktop using [these instructions](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/INSTALL). This requires boost >= v1.69. I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 in a Windows subsystem (WSL), and there is no repository for this version of boost. Consequently, I installed boost v1.70 from source using [these instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/boost.html).

However, when I run the `cmake` command in the RStudio install instructions, I get this:

```
(base) balter@spectre3:~$  cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DRSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD=1
CMake Error: The source directory "/home" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
(base) balter@spectre3:~$ cd rstudio/build/
(base) balter@spectre3:~/rstudio/build$  cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DRSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD=1
-- CMake build type not set; defaulting to debug build
-- Found Boost 1.70.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED
-- Found boost_headers 1.70.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.70.0
-- Boost 1.69.0 found.
-- Found Boost 1.70.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS atomic;chrono;date_time;filesystem;iostreams;program_options;random;regex;system;thread
-- Found boost_atomic 1.70.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.70.0
-- No suitable boost_atomic variant has been identified!
--   libboost_atomic.so.1.70.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:95 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.70.0/boost_atomic-config.cmake

  but it set boost_atomic_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_atomic" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:124 (boost_find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:261 (find_package)
  src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:235 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The last bits of the log files are:

**CMakeOutput.log**

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Determining if the function inotify_init1 exists passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/home/balter/conda/bin/make" "cmTC_bd56e/fast"
/home/balter/conda/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=inotify_init1 -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_bd56e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=inotify_init1  -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  CMakeFiles/cmTC_bd56e.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_bd56e
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Determining if the function setresuid exists passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/home/balter/conda/bin/make" "cmTC_af28b/fast"
/home/balter/conda/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=setresuid -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_af28b
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=setresuid  -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  CMakeFiles/cmTC_af28b.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_af28b
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

**CMakeOutput.log**

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/home/balter/conda/bin/make" "cmTC_6613e/fast"
/home/balter/conda/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe  -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_6613e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe   -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_6613e 
/home/balter/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text.startup+0x3): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6613e.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_6613e] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_6613e/fast] Error 2

File /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/home/balter/conda/bin/make" "cmTC_c8506/fast"
/home/balter/conda/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_c8506
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create  -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_c8506 -lpthreads 
/home/balter/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c8506.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_c8506] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_c8506/fast] Error 2


Determining if the function getpeereid exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/home/balter/conda/bin/make" "cmTC_b9b1c/fast"
/home/balter/conda/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_b9b1c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/balter/conda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid  -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_b9b1c 
/home/balter/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: in function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text.startup+0xd): undefined reference to `getpeereid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b9b1c.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_b9b1c] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/balter/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_b9b1c/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the BLFS instructions built only shared libraries but the RStudio Desktop build is explicitly asking for static libraries.

Comment: @DanielSchepler--can you suggest a fix?

Comment: To quote the comments from the BLFS instructions: `link=shared`: ... Omit this parameter if you do need static libraries.

Comment: Add that as an answer please!